# How to fixed menu and changing pages in Electron.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

(sorry for my bad english)

Hello. How can I make a fixed menu and changing html like vscode on the electron.js? For example, get a menu. We have 3 html files in one:

```
page1.html
page2.html
page3.html
```

When I click on `page1` in the menu, it will go to page1 and the menu will remain fixed. At the same time, when I click on page2, it will go to page2 and again, the menu will remain fixed.I tried redirected to the html pages as follows:

```
ipcMain.on("goPage1",(err,data) => {
    mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/page1.html`)
})
```

right its work,but I do not know this correct. In fact, I can do this to keep the menu fixed on every page, maybe, get a `base.html`. here get a menu.Also get a div element with the id `# myDiv`. Let's do `page1.html`. I don't know if this is the right way. To summarize the topic: How can we make a fixed menu like vscode and changing pages? What I said above is the right way? What is the best way to do them?
Thank you for reading so far, my friend. I will be very happy if you answer my questions. I am looking forward to your reply.thanks now...

Comment: really nobody not know answer?or my english is very bad?if my english is bad,please tell me i rewrite this question.

Comment: It's not clear (to me at least) what you are asking. Which "menu" are you referring to, the window menu? Do you want it to change based on the current page?

Comment: think vscode.menu on left.and menu buttons route we pages.but menu is fixed.i found this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55462919/how-should-multiple-html-files-be-rendered-in-a-single-window-within-electron.and this work for me.but this is right way?example:vscode how doing this?
I hope I could explain

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now – a fixed sidebar which functions as a "menu". I haven't needed to do that before. I wonder if VSCode uses the `tab` functionality for that?